# Show a message box when a row is added to data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, messagebox

I'm adding data to datagrid view from some text boxes using a button in the button click event. I want to show a message in a message box when a row is added from those text boxes.
here's my code to add a record.

Program Code

```
//Create a new row in grid view
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

//Create cells
row.CreateCells(this.mygrid, txtId.Text, txtFname.Text, txtLname.Text, txtEmail.Text);

//add to data grid view
this.mygrid.Rows.Add(row);
```

can anyone give me the code to show a message box when a record ( a data row) is added to the grid view..

Comment: There is a `RowsAdded` event, try it and ask again when you encounter a problem. If you want me just to do your work it will be 150eur/hour

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows Form's code:

```
MessageBox.Show("..");
```

Make sure you have System.Windows.Forms as being used, but if it's a windows form that should not be a problem.

If you don't want to put it under this.mygrid.Rows.Add(row), you could also make an event for it:

```
//Create a new row in grid view
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

//Create cells
row.CreateCells(this.mygrid, txtId.Text, txtFname.Text, txtLname.Text, txtEmail.Text);

//add to data grid view
this.mygrid.Rows.Add(row);
//Throw mygrid_RowsAdded when a row is added.
mygrid.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(mygrid_RowsAdded);


void mygrid_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("...");
}
```

Or if you only want the box to be shown when a user adds a row:

```
mygrid.UserAddedRow += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(mygrid_RowsAdded);
```